# how I can include a second Compact RIO chassis in my labview project

Tags: fpga, labview, daq-mx

I'm currently using the NI-9047 to build a capture system, but since the system update requires some IO ports to expand my project, I need to add a cRIO NI-9054.
When I added the 9054 to the project, I had an error in my acquisition system, and the new 9054 could only read the value collected by the C module once. I would like to ask you: How do I read the data of two CRIO correctly?
What I'm doing now is using the QMH framework, which uses a time structure to read sequentially in a while loop
[image]

What I'm doing now is using the QMH framework, which uses a time structure to read sequentially in a while loop.Should I use two While loops to read data from each chassis?

ps：The system is in FPGA mode.